# Unity stuck on build : Enable Android Gradle templates?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to build my android game made in Unity. I have build this game 2 years,nut now i get infinity build loop and dialog with title: Enable Android Gradle templates? and i can't dismiss this dialog ,because Build dialog is modal

Please see image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In playerSettings>publishingSettings Enabling all these custom properties worked for me. Try it.

[image]